# Calculation of eigenvalue of Laplace in hyperbolic plane

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

$H=R\times(0,\infty)$ is the hyperbolic plane. $\omega= i$ and $z=x+iy$. $d_H$ is the distance function of $H$.Consider
$$
l=d_H(z,\omega)=\ln \dfrac{|z-\overline \omega|+|z-\omega|}{|z-\overline \omega|-|z-\omega|} =\ln\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}+\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}-\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}}   \\
f(\cosh l)=\int_0^1（\cosh l+\sinh l \sin 2\pi x）^{-1/2+ic} dx
$$
$c$ is a constant. If the Laplace operator is $\Delta=y^2(\partial_{xx}+\partial_{yy})$, then , how to show
$$
\Delta f(\cosh l)=-\bigg(\frac{1}{4}+c^2\bigg)f(\cosh l)
$$

I try to use Maple to calculate it . But fail.

In fact, I am not sure whether the distance function is right .